# Is there a python equivalent of the prefuse visualization toolkit?

Tags: python, visualization, prefuse

The [prefuse visualization toolkit](http://prefuse.org/) is pretty nice, but for Java.  I was wondering if there was something similar for python.  My primary interest is being able to navigate dynamic graphs.

Comment: I'm looking to do something very similar, and haven't found anything comparable to NodeBox or Prefuse (flare) for python.  I'll be following this question closely.

Answer (score 6):

I know this is not exactly python, but you could use prefuse in python *through* [jython](http://jython.org)

Something along the lines of:

Add prefuse to your path:

`export JYTHONPATH=$JYTHONPATH:prefuse.jar`

and

`>>> import prefuse`

from your jython machinery

this [guy](http://github.com/fajran) has an example of using prefuse from jython [here](http://gist.github.com/32288)

Answer (score 3):

You might want to check out [SUMMON](http://people.csail.mit.edu/rasmus/summon/index.shtml), a visualization system that uses python but handles fairly large data sets.  There's an impressive video of visualizing and navigating a massive tree.  (Can't post the link because I'm a first time poster.  It's on the SUMMON front page.)

Comment: SUMMON looks nice, but appears to be only for the desktop.  Looks like prefuse/flare are more web-oriented.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using a Mac, check out [NodeBox](http://nodebox.net/code/index.php/Home). One extension it offers is a [graph library](http://nodebox.net/code/index.php/Graphing) that looks pretty good. Poke around in the [NodeBox gallery](http://nodebox.net/code/index.php/Gallery) some to find something similar to your problem and it should have some helpful links.

Answer (score 1):

This is well after OP, but just in case:

[pydot](http://dkbza.org/pydot.html). Allows generation & rendering of graphs.  If you need graph algorithms (transitive closure etc.) also look at pygraphlib which extends and integrates pydot.

Note that neither allows interactive editing of the rendered diagram.  They both use graphviz to generate output.

Answer (score 0):

Note that prefuse now has the [flare](http://flare.prefuse.org/) package which uses flash.

Connect that to a Python backend via [web2py](http://mdp.cti.depaul.edu/) and you've got a great web app (just an idea).

Answer (score 0):

You could try using prefuse with [JPype](http://jpype.sourceforge.net/), if you can't find a suitable replacement.

Answer (score -1):

[MayaVi](http://mayavi.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: That's quite different from prefuse.  Too powerful and complex for what prefuse is great for.