# javascript package for category theory (or graph) diagrams?

Tags: javascript, graph, visualization, diagram, category-theory

I'm looking for a Javascript package that will help me write category theory diagrams. Basically, creating dots with labels and arrows between the dots (where more than one arrow can connect two dots and a dot can be connected to itself). Plus, the ability to specify line types (solid / dashed).

Specifically, I want something that will automatically layout the elements for me.

I saw canviz but apparently it requires graphviz to prerender the diagrams. I also saw dracula, but apparently it can't draw arcs from a node to itself.

Comment: Possible dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7034/graph-visualization-code-in-javascript

Comment: I saw these before and looked at all suggestions, but non seemed to fit. Maybe someone more familiar with them can outline how they can be used for my needs (specifically, arrows from a node to itself seems to be missing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe [infovis](http://thejit.org/) or [protovis](http://vis.stanford.edu/protovis/ex/)? See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6422603/circuit-block-diagram-drawing/6424854#6424854) for some other graph rendering possibilities.

hth.

Comment: aren't all of these about charting?

Comment: Not just charting.  They do force-directed layout too, see e.g. http://thejit.org/static/v20/Jit/Examples/ForceDirected/example2.html